# How to get date time of a server in yii2 php

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

Is there any way to `GET` the current date and time of the server in `YiII`?

One solution I have found is below

```
'created_at' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'), But I don't know it's correct or not.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: any time when you used date-time, it gives server date time only.

Comment: What do you mean GET? DB and server time may be different.

Comment: I want to GET the date time of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this through php by using `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')` or `date($format)` where `$format` contains the format in which you want the time. This by default gives you date and time for now.

You can take a look at the manual for the formats to use: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php